# How to bring generics into a java stream

Tags: java, generics

I have a third-party method returning just `List` with no generics. I want to stream this list and I know it contains a specific type, for example `String`.

Is there an elegant way to deal with this?

```
long containA = externalMethodReturningList()
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> s.contains("a"))  // compiler error here
    .count();

// I cannot change the signature:
List externalMethodReturningList() {  
    return List.of("aba", "bbc", "cab");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: My original thought was to map the elements of the `Stream` to `String`s:

```
long containA = externalMethodReturningList()
    .stream()
    .map(Object::toString)
    .filter(s -> s.contains("a")) 
    .count();
```

However, this doesn't work, since calling `stream()` on a raw `List` produces a raw `Stream`, which will remain a raw `Stream` even after the `map` operation.

A solution that would work is to cast the `Stream` to a `Stream<String>`:

```
long containA = 
    ((Stream<String>)externalMethodReturningList().stream())
        .filter(s -> s.contains("a")) 
        .count();
```

A bit ugly, I know.

It would probably be cleaner to wrap `externalMethodReturningList()` with a method that returns a `List<String>`, and use that wrapper method as a source to the `Stream` pipeline.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this solution, but I don't find it elegant. In my case, the method is on another object, so looks like `method1(...).execute(...).getList()` and casting is really ugly there. I hoped a better way is there, but probably not. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Barney Perhaps you should split the chain of calls into two statements. The first assigns the raw List returned by the method to a `List<String>` variable, and the second runs the pipeline on the generic List.

Comment: This is my actual solution indeed, but I'm bit disappointed by Java now :-)

Answer (score 2):

The legacy shouldn't really affect your other code that much. So I think there's no need for an extra step in stream pipeline or anything like that - just cast the list:

```
long containA = ((List<String>) externalMethodReturningList())
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> s.contains("a"))
    .count();
```

Then, once you *can* change the signature, you just remove the cast, and everything else is back to normal.